# How to run Microsoft Excel macro automatically everytime it get changed?

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to know if there's a way to run the macro when I change the content inside the document. Thank you!

The macro:

```
Sub Test()
    Const QT = """"
    Dim a(), i As Long, r As Long, v As String
    With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        If .Count = 1 Then
            ReDim a(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            a(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            a() = .Value
        End If
        For r = 1 To UBound(a)
            v = Trim(a(r, 1))
            If Len(v) Then
                If Right(v, 1) = QT Then v = Left(v, Len(v) - 1)
                i = InStrRev(v, QT)
                If i Then v = Mid(v, i + 1)
                a(r, 1) = Trim(v)
            End If
        Next
        .Value = a()
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: look into [Worksheet.Change Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx) or [Workbook.SheetChange Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event handler to the workbook as follows

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox ("changed")
End Sub
```

To add this macro go to the vb view - in the left hand Project panel select the workbook to open the code associated with the workbook and paste the code above.  Every time you change a cell in the workbook you will receive the notification.